# #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server error

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I cannot log in to my mySQL database server anymore.

I am currently using WAMP 2.2 on Windows 8.1 64 bits.

I tried reinstalling WAMP server but the problem still persists.

I have also edited the config.inc.php file and changed the host name from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'; however the problem still exists.

Comment: What colour is your wampmanger icon?

Comment: I figured out the solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, eventually. It had nothing to do with any of the configuration files though.
My ESET Smart Security antivirus updated silently and blocked the mysql application. I did not even get a notification for it!
I figured it out when I tried logging in to phpMyadmin after turning off my antivirus.

[image]

I had to allow communication for mysqld.exe in the antivirus settings.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Wampmanager menus take a look at the mysql error log.

left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL log

If that does not show any [error] messages then also have a look at the 'Windows Event Viewer' in the 'Application' section for messages from MySQL.

The normal problem is a rogue 'my.ini' or 'my.cnf' file on your system. Search for these 2 files in the C;\windows folder, if you find any then delete them.

DO NOT DELETE THE my.ini FILE FREOM ANYWHERE IN THE C;\WAMP folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered a problem with MySQL, It was showing an error “Error : 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly” when I tried to start the service in services.msc

So I googled it but didn’t found the perfect solution. I will show how can you debug the issue. First look for file my.ini which can be found in “C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17″ , open that file on look for “log-error”, this will show you the path where error log is stored. In my case it is, “c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log”.

Open the log file and look for last error you got, you should be today’s date when you tried to start the wampmysqld from services. At this stage, you will get error and understand what it say. In my case it is,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvGwR.jpg)

The folders for all databases are in “C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data”. To fix I moved kmk folder to some other place. After this, wampmysqld in services.msc is getting started without any error.